# Mysql LOAD command

Tags: mysql

Mysql LOAD command lets import data from csv files

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE table_main
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

What if there are multiple relation tables

```
table_main
    id
    firstname
    lastname

table_type
    id
    table_main_id
    table_type_id

table_type
    id
    typename
```

Is it possible to load a csv file with content like below with LOAD command

```
firstname, lastname, typename
john,doe,mytypename
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it it not possible with `LOAD DATA` syntax to insert into multiple tables. A possible workaround is loading it into a temporary table & take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

No, IMHO. You would have to

- first LOAD to temporary table, then
- do the 3 INSERT statements and finally
- DROP the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an array that holds the tables names and iterate for each table name .

```
$tables = array("table1","table2","table3","tableN");

foreach ($tables as $table ) {

 try
     {
      $this->connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name",$db_user, $db_pass,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true)); 

         $this->connect->exec("LOAD DATA INFILE  'data.csv' INTO TABLE 
                            ".$table_name." 
                  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ";

   }
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {  
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }
```

I hope that's solve your problem.